# USB signal analysis

Tags: usb, communication, reverse-engineering

I have a device that I want to control it has window software that runs it, and a complex interface. I just need a pair of commands, also I know very little about usb device hacking, and signal analysis.

I looked up USB protocol analyzers, but they are expensive.
The software runs in windows, but I only know how to capture USB traffic in linux.

The device is a spectrometer. I think it is a character device.
I just need to capture the signal that tells the spectrometer to sample.

I have an idea, but I am looking for better ideas. 
my idea is to splice in a USB cable into the usb cable that is controlling the spectrometer. then in linux, I will be running

```
sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/usbmon/3u > usbOutput.txt
```

If anyone knows a better way to capture the commands sent by a program to a device, I would be very much interested.

Comment: I don't have time for full answer, but you could capture traffic in Windows using Wireshark and then figure out what's going on. [Here](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/USB#Windows)'s a relevant link. I don't think that splicing will work good. Furthermore Wireshark solution is software-only, so very little effort is lost if it doesn't work out.

Comment: You cannot sensibly splice USB cables.

Comment: Can you tell me why I can't splice a USB cable? what part of that strikes you as being non-functional?

Comment: Because usb hosts aren't passive devices and need enumeration and it just won't work like tapping a serial or Ethernet cable would.

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/117474/how-to-sniff-a-usb-port-under-windows